# Can not apply commission concerns to component Late bound because it appears to be a target-less proxy. Currently those are not supported

Tags: c#, tdd, moq, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I designed a simple unit test pattern and used the moq library. But an exception is thrown when executing `Container.Resolve<IInterface>()` method. The following is the registration method for Castle Windsor:

```
container.Register(Component.For<TBase>().UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
{
    var mockObject = new Mock<TBase>();
    var mockType = typeof(TBase);

    if (container is Core.IoCContainer.IoCCore.CustomContainer)
    {
        var resolvingDelege = (container as Core.IoCContainer.IoCCore.CustomContainer).ResolvingTestDelegateList[mockType];

        if (resolvingDelege != null)
        {
            resolvingDelege(mockType, mockObject);
        }
    }

    return mockObject.Object;
})
.LifestyleTransient());
```

while executing `IoCCore.Container.Resolve< ISampleDataContext>();`, an exception is being thrown. The exception message is "Can not apply commission concerns to component Late bound Data.Context.ISampleDataContext because it appears to be a target-less proxy. Currently those are not supported."

I searched for the problem and found that `mockObject.Object` is `Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor`. Thus, while resolving instance then code below in the `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator` class is where  the problem occurs:

```
protected virtual void ApplyCommissionConcerns(object instance)
    {
        if (Model.Lifecycle.HasCommissionConcerns == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        instance = ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedInstance(instance);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            // see http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-332 for details
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Can not apply commission concerns to component {0} because it appears to be a target-less proxy. Currently those are not supported.", Model.Name));
        }
        ApplyConcerns(Model.Lifecycle.CommissionConcerns, instance);
    }
```

The object being resolved by `UsingFactoryMethod` is  `Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor`, which is created by mock object. But, Castle Windsor assumes that `IProxyTargetAccessor` is created by itself instead of mock object. This causes an empty instance of `CommissionConcerns` is being returned from my mock instance.

Is there a possible workaround for this bug? Should I wait for an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a workaround for this problem. I changed UseFactoryMethod method instead of the code below

```
Component.For<TBase>().UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
            {
                var mockObject = new Mock<TBase>();
                var mockType = typeof(TBase);

                if (container is Core.IoCContainer.IoCCore.CustomContainer)
                {
                    var resolvingDelege = (container as Core.IoCContainer.IoCCore.CustomContainer).ResolvingTestDelegateList[mockType];

                    if (resolvingDelege != null)
                    {
                        resolvingDelege(mockType, mockObject);
                    }
                }

                //The code that was changed
                //==============================================
                var type = mockObject.Object.GetType();
                var field = type.GetField("__target");

                field.SetValue(mockObject.Object, new Object());
                //==============================================

                return mockObject.Object;
            })
            .LifestyleTransient());
```